# Can not get HTML Document from a Jsoup Connection for a specific website

Tags: java, html, netbeans, jsoup

When I try to request the HTML Document after connecting to this specific website (this error hasn't occured when I've used Jsoup for other website) I receive the next error.

Code:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.twicenest.com/index.php?mid=schedule&pGanjioption=1&pYear=" + date.getYear() + "&pMonth=" + date.getMonthValue()).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36").get();

// do something with doc
```

Error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:117)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.jsoup.internal.ConstrainableInputStream.read(ConstrainableInputStream.java:64)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:212)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:289)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.jsoup.parser.CharacterReader.bufferUp(CharacterReader.java:53)
    at org.jsoup.parser.CharacterReader.consume(CharacterReader.java:98)
    at org.jsoup.parser.TokeniserState$40.read(TokeniserState.java:803)
    at org.jsoup.parser.Tokeniser.read(Tokeniser.java:57)
    at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.runParser(TreeBuilder.java:51)
    at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:45)
    at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:39)
    at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseInputStream(DataUtil.java:153)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:851)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:296)
    at view.ONCEApp.start(ONCEApp.java:51)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
```

I've tried to read from this website using the build in Java tools (URL, URLConnection) and have succeeded in that by using these. But they don't provide the same filter methods that Jsoup does.